# Simultaneously dismissing a view controller and then presenting one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

So I have a VC that i call on when a button is clicked (It's a MFMailComposeViewController) and when the message is sent, It dismisses the ViewController and i want it to present a different one once it's done sending. But instead of doing this it crashes after sending the email every time. i know I'm doing something wrong but i'm not sure what.

Here's my code that dismisses and presents the new one.

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
[self presentViewController:_emailConfirmationPage animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

I was thinking that the problem was that I used `self` but I'm not sure what I use in place of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is crashing because you are asking for both dismiss and present animations to begin simultaneously. So you can fix this in 2 ways:

1. Wait for the first animation to complete before starting the next one. This will animate the dismissal of the current VC and animate the presentation of the new one. Of course the user would have to wait for both animations to complete before they can continue interacting with the app. To do this, present `_emailConfirmationPage` in the completion block of dismissing the current VC like this:

   ```
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
       [self presentViewController:_emailConfirmationPage animated:YES completion:nil];
   }];
   ```
2. Animate either dismiss OR present, but not both. This might be better because the user would have to wait only for 1 animation and that 1 animation will most probably be sufficient to ensure a fluid user experience.

   ```
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
   [self presentViewController:_emailConfirmationPage animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```

Comment: I didn't realize until now but my app still crashes. Nothing has really changed either.

Answer (score 3):

Try put your `[self presentViewController:_emailConfirmationPage animated:YES completion:nil];}` into `completion:` block in the `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];` , it will execute present vc after it has complete dismiss the other vc

Like this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:_emailConfirmationPage animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```

Your code did not work because its still animating `dismissViewController` and there can't be 2 animation at the same time

Comment: I'm a little confused. How would i put the [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil]; into the [self presentViewController:_emailConfirmationPage animated:YES completion:nil];?

Comment: u put it in the `nil` part in `block` format, please see my edit

Comment: Shouldn't that be the other way around? Don't I want it to present the View Controller after it's been dismissed?

Comment: ah because i saw you use `dismiss` first then u only call `present`?, but its just the idea, u can just revert it the way u want :D